# Python strptime : time data 'January 03 2017' does not match format '%b %d %Y'

Tags: python, date, strptime

```
dateCreated = datetime.strptime(item['dateCreated'].replace(',',''), '%b %d %Y')
```

^^ code ^^

```
Python strptime : time data 'January 03 2017' does not match format '%b %d %Y'
```

^^ error ^^

Running Python 2.7

I know that similar questions have been asked, but none of the answers matched my situation.

Comment: `%B` not `%b`. You have the full month name. `%b` is for abbreviated month name e.g. "Jan"

Answer (score 3):

Take a closer look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) (emphasis mine):

> %b - Month as locale’s **abbreviated** name. (Jan, Feb, …, Dec)
>
> %B - Month as locale’s **full** name. (January, February, …, December)

You want `'%B %d %Y'`, not `'%b %d %Y'`.

Answer (score 1):

`%b` is for the abbreviated month name.  You want `%B`.